# Flexbox: é possível controlar a quantidade de itens alinhados com o "space-between"?

Tags: css3, flexbox

Tenho o seguinte caso, uma div pai com 5 divs filhas, e preciso que elas se alinhem de duas em duas, utilizando o space-between na div pai:

```
.pai{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width:200px;
}
```

Porém a div filha é pequena o suficiente para caber mais que duas dentro da div pai. Existe alguma maneira de deixar apenas duas por linha dentro da div pai?

Exemplo:

```css
.pai{
width:280px;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
flex-wrap:wrap;
background:#ccc;
}
.filha{
  height:40px;
  width:75px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filha">
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="filha">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="filha">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="filha">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="filha">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente não tem como, a unica solução (mantendo as flexbox), é adicionar um container a cada 2 div´s filhas mesmo...

```css
.pai{
width:280px;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
flex-wrap:wrap;
background:#ccc;
}
.filha{
  height:40px;
  width:75px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">

  <div>
    <div class="filha"></div>

    <div class="filha"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="filha"></div>

    <div class="filha"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```